# How to scrape data from a website, that has a table that needs scrolling to display all data?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, node-horseman

This website has a table that only display 100 rows at a time. You need to scroll further to display more rows. I'm using Node.js and Horseman + PhantomJS to **scrape** data, but I want to find an efficient way of scraping the whole table, not just 100 rows at a time.

```
var h = new Horseman({timeout: 20000});
    
h
.open(<<link>>)
    .waitForSelector("table.GridListings")
    .text("td.ListingID")
    .then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
```

What further modifications can I do, to scroll through the entire table and fetch all data?

Comment: check javascript rendering

Comment: @eLRuLL Tried $(".ListingID").text(), only displays the first 100 results.

Comment: FYI it’s scrape not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.scrollTo(top, left)` to scroll to the bottom of the page and keep doing it until no new content is being loaded for some time.

Then you can check the table that should be populated with all of the fields.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I was hoping for a more efficient method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @AthanasiosCanko The only other thing you could do would be to go to that website, open the console, see network connections and see what data is actually being transmitted and from which URLs, and then use those URLs together will all the required fields and headers to access the same data without using the website - but make sure that you're not breaking any terms and conditions while you do it. I'm glad that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use phantomjs  instance to evaluate javascript and scrooll to windows bottom

```
   .evaluate(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of your code? "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." See: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: it just uses phantomjs  instance to evaluate javascript that  scrooll to windows bottom

Answer (score 0):

I think, in this case you should scroll (.scrollTo(top, left) method) and wait (probably, .waitFor(fn, [arg1, arg2,...], value) method) for table being repopulated. I guess, you should repeat the actions until number of rows in the table equals to "Number of Listings" in the "Results Summary" block.